# JBoss AS 7, EJB3 cast to interface

Tags: ejb, jboss7.x

I'm facing weird behavior with JBoss AS 7 and my application which uses EJB3.1.
I successfully lookup bean but when Im trying to cast it to its interface, exception is thrown.

Code in short:

```
@Local
public interface BusinessObjectsFactory { ... }

@Stateless
@Local(BusinessObjectsFactory.class)
public class JPABusinessObjectsFactory implements BusinessObjectsFactory { ... }

...
Object obj = ctx.lookup("java:app/moduleName/" +
    "JPABusinessObjectsFactory!pckg.BusinessObjectsFactory");
Class c = obj.getClass();
System.out.println(c.getName()); // pckg.BusinessObjectsFactory$$$view36
System.out.println(c.getInterfaces()[0].getName()); // BusinessObjectsFactory 

BusinessObjectsFactory bof = (BusinessObjectsFactory) obj; //cast exception
```

Any ideas? Note that interface is needed (which implementation is looked up is read from configuration file and might change)

Comment: 1. You have your application executed on the server and where is the client? On the same server, within the same application?
2. Are you using EJB-jar modules or WAR packaging?
3. (minor) if you specify \@Local on your interface you doesn't need to do this once again on the class level. One \@Local is enough.

Comment: Are the client and target EJBs located in separate WARs?  What do c.getInterfaces()[0].getClassLoader() and BusinessObjectsFactory.class.getClassLoader() return?

Comment: Well im kinda new in packaging such archives. What I want is separate EJB modules (lets say EJB module for persistence and EJB module with business logic which uses this persitence module). The application logic should call persitence module via some interface. Thats why i created this structure:

Comment: **interfaces-jar** inlucdes BusinessObjectsFactory interface, **jpa-persistence.jar** knows and implements interfaces.jar, **applogic.jar** knows interfaces.jar and does JNDI lookup java:app/JPABusinessFactory

Comment: Im building applications by maven. If there is some good example how to achieve this (how to correcly set dependencies and what should and shouldn't include specific EJB jars)...

Comment: To your questions: these are EJB JAR packages, interfaces.jar are simple JAR included in both of these packages. And they are (and will be) deployed on the same server

Comment: @d1x - are those artifacts wrapped into single war and deployed so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched to another lookup strategy while this is no longer issue for me. I'm not sure if this is still present in newest versions of JBoss/Wildfly AS. That's why I'm closing this question.